# jQuery - Change Iframe height in the onclick event of a button inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, iframe

Right now i am working on a simple HTML/jQuery script where i want to change the iframe height when i'm clicking on a button which is loaded by the iframe it self.

Take a look at my code:

index.php:

```
<div id="outerdiv">
    <iframe src="http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/test/iframe.php" id="inneriframe" scrolling="no"    target="_parent"></iframe>
</div>
```

iframe.php:

```
 <HTML>
 <head>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#SuperWebF1").click(function(){

        $('#inneriframe, #outerdiv', window.parent.document).css({"height":"450px"});

    })
    </script>
 <div style="display:block;height:300px;">
    <h3>The iframe content</h3>  
        <button type="button" id="SuperWebF1">Click me to resize the holding Iframe!</button>
  </div>
```

Here is a demo of the index.php: http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/test/

When you open it you'll see the button which is loaded by the iframe.
When you click the button the iframe is not changing height!

Why, is there a mistake?

Can you help me make this thing work ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to bind the click event to the button element before it exists.

Comment: Is there any way that i can place the script outside the iframe and make it listen in there is a click inside that iframe on the button ?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some changes I made to your code.

```
//function call needed to make sure page is loaded before javascript runs
$(document).ready(function(){//begin document ready function

//on click event
$(document).on("click","#SuperWebF1",function(){//begin on click event

    //change the height of selected elements
    $('#inneriframe, #outerdiv', window.parent.document).css({"height":"450px"});

    });//end on click event


  });//end document ready function
```

Comment: Is there any way that i can place the script outside the iframe and make it listen in there is a click inside that iframe on the button

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the contents of your iframe before you can setup your click event. Try this -

```
var iframeDoc = $('#inneriframe').contents().get(0);
$(iframeDoc).on('click', 'SuperWebF1', function() {
       ........... your code here  .............
});
```

Happy Coding!!!